# How to pass a value to $scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and have inherited code base that has it.  I'm trying to perform a simple task, but am lost.  I don't know what I don't know (we've all been there) and I'm not sure how to ask this.

```
// Has Discounts
$scope.isDiscountAreaOpen = function(val) {
    if (val == "true") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

If I set val=true then a panel slides open on a page.  Based on the user type which is determined in the back end code I need to pass 'true' to this (I think), so the panel opens - or maybe I need to do it a different way?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking?

Comment: First, why isDiscountAreaOpen has to be a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.Language = 'Hindi';
        $scope.Preference = function(lang) {
           $scope.Language = lang;
        };    

        $scope.Preference1 = function(lang, lang1) {
           $scope.Language = lang;
           $scope.Language1 = lang1;
        };    
    }]);
</script>

<h2>Attach functions or behavior with arguments - AngularJS</h2>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
Click 
<button ng-click="Preference('English')">English</button>
<button ng-click="Preference('Hindi')">Hindi</button>
<button ng-click="Preference('Spanish')">Spanish</button>
<button ng-click="Preference1('French', ' and Hindi language also.')">French</button>
<p>I like {{ Language}} language {{ Language1 }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw this in my research.  No idea of how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you call your function in the template, I'll try to guess:
I assume you have a class that opens the sidebar, let's call it `"sidebar-open"`. Also introduce a new variable

```
$scope.isDiscountAreaOpen = function(val) {
    if (val == "true") {
        $scope.isOpen = true;
    } else {
        $scope.isOpen = false;
    }
};
```

in HTML should be something like this:

```
<div class="sidebar" ng-class="{'sidebar-open': isOpen}">
...
</div>
...
<button ng-click="isDiscountAreaOpen('true')">Open</button>
<button ng-click="isDiscountAreaOpen('false')">Close</button>
```